# regular expression to add a target="blank" to all external links

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom

Is it possible to add a `target="_blank"` to all `<a>` tags, with just one regular expression?  I've been experimenting with negative and positive look aheads/behinds, to no avail.  This should:

- Match anchor tags whose `href` starts with `http://`
- If the anchor tag does not have a `target` tag, adds a `target="_blank"` tag
- If it does have a `target` tag, it checks if the `target` tag is not already set to `"_blank"`, and if not it is replaced to `target="_blank"`

Is this possible? If not, what would be the least computationally intensive way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a script (e.g. Javascript) embedded inside a html page or are you running a program against a html file?

Comment: you want a regular expression to set something? aren't they used to match strings with patterns ?

Comment: [A regular expression to parse (and modify) HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Keep in mind that in HTML, there's not a strict order for tag attributes. So that both `<a href="#" target="_blank"></a>` and `<a target="_blank" href="#"></a>` are valid.

Comment: @peachykeen: Common people, stop pasting this link. I think everybody has already seen it and it's a bit unfair to gain your reputation by simply linking it... Although it's funny.

Comment: @DioF: You don't gain rep from comment votes, so linking it is just good fun (and a warning to the OP to not actually try to use just regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really specify whether this would be the html from the DOM (among other things). Assuming you want to modify the DOM... Using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a').filter( function() {
        return $(this).attr('href').substr(0, 7) == "http://";
    }).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

here is a jsfiddle showing it works (you can inspect the elements to see that the `a`'s with `href`'s starting with `http://` have `target="_blank"`) : http://jsfiddle.net/amRrj/

Comment: It was originally intended to be server-side, and HTML from a CMS. However, this will be outputted to a page, and actually I like your idea of pushing the computation to the client-side, via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is also well-formed XML then you would be better off using an XML tool with support for xpath and xslt.  Take a look at [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) which provides tools similar to grep, sed etc for working with XML.  I think this would do what you want, but I have not tried it:

```
xml ed -P -S -i //a -t attr -n target -v _blank somefile.html >somefile_2.html
```

`xml ed` invokes the XMLStarlet edit command

`-P` preserve formatting

`-S` preserve whitespace

`-i //a` insert at every  tag

`-t attr` insert type is attribute

`-n target` name of attribute to insert

`-v _blank` value of attribute to insert

For more complex editing you can use XMLStarlet with an xslt transform.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is adding `target="_blank"` to the `<base href…>`. This will globally affect the pages `<a>` tag targets rather than needing to add them individually. Target declarations on `<a>` tags will override this.

```js
    var target = '_self';

    if(external){
        target = '_blank';
    }

    $('#base_tag').attr('target', target);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robstarbuck/0jhmktx1/9/)

[<base> Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 0):

I write this one maybe it helps:

Regex: `/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/gi`

```js
console.log(`<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/test" target="_parent">Stackoverflow</a>`.replace(/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>'));
console.log(`<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/test" target="_target">Stackoverflow</a>`.replace(/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>'));
console.log(`<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/test">Stackoverflow</a>`.replace(/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>'));
```